# I'm not your clone

Tags: riddle, rhyme, english

> I can bring good, when only one you own
>   Leave me hanging, I'll be fine alone
>
> For your amusement, I could be thrown
>   And I won't break, I'm tough like stone
>
> By your friends, I could be step on
>   Without them, I would never be known
>
> And here is last clue
>   To make your mind blown
>   I look like you
>   But I'm not your clone

**What am I?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer could be

> a horseshoe.

I can bring good, when only one you own
Leave me hanging, I'll be fine alone

> Hanging a horseshoe above the door is sometimes considered lucky.

For your amusement, I could be thrown
And I won't break, I'm tough like stone

> Throwing horseshoes is [a popular game](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Horseshoes). And of course, it doesn't easily break.

By your friends, I could be step on
Without them, I would never be known

> Horseshoes are put on by horses ("friends"), and without horses, they would be nonexistent. (Thanks, Will!)

And here is last clue
To make your mind blown
I look like you
But I'm not your clone

> It looks like "U", but obviously is not my clone.

Comment: Lines 5-6 (fourth spoiler) refer to horses....

Comment: @Will Thanks, added that! (And I feel so stupid having missed the most obvious one... :/)